# Connect node.js PostgreSQL database and Vue client locally

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js

New to all of this so this might be the wrong setup. I have set up one project which uses node to connect to a postgreSQL. This works and I can start this from VS Code using:

```
node index.js
```

and the response is:

```
App running on port 3000.
```

Another project is a client and has been created Vue. This is started using

```
npm run serve
```

The response is:

```
App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
```

The Vue client gets data from a source using the code below and then displays it. In this example it uses some dummy data and works fine.

```
created: function () {
    axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .then(res => {
            this.users = res.data;
        })
}
```

However if I change the source above to communicate with the local postgreSQL database server:

```
.get('http://localhost:3000/users/')
```

I quite rightly get the security issue in the browser console when trying to connect:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/users/. (Reason: CORS
> header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

So how do I intergrate the node.js part and the vue client part?

UPDATE

The answer to the question is below but I changed very slightly. The following was added to the index.js file (the node postgreSQL part). It is importing cors and saying allow conneciton from localhost:8080. Works perfectly:

```
import cors from 'cors';

const corsOptions = {
   origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

Comment: you need to allow cors on the server. By default is is not allowed to make a request from somewhere other than the page is served. If the frontend and backend are on different servers, you get cors problems.  Always use google too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: As I said I understand why there is a CORS issue. My question was asking 1) whether this is a reasonable set up and 2) if so how to get around the issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by if your setup is reasonable. For solving the problem you should set headers on your Axios method. And in your back-end, you should allow the CORS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install lib [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). For that in your project folder just run the command:
`npm i --save cors`

After that lib is installed you should import and configure in your server application. To enable your front-end communicate with server side application.

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors'); //<--install this lib

const app = express();

cors({ credentials: true, origin: true });//enable some headers for handling authentication tokens
app.use(cors());//use in your server
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') { app.use(logger('dev')); }

app.use(require('./server/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

As stated by the documentation, when you use the function `cors()` its equivallent to:

```
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```

Comment: Thank you - helped me get to the answer that I have listed in the update to the question. Really helpful.